# Google App Engine ndb query fetch_page very slow for small amount of entities

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

The following query seems to take an way too long

```
t0 = time.time()

# Fetch the entities and return result with cursor
result, next_cursor, more = MyModel.query(MyModel.active == True, MyModel.offline == False).fetch_page(pagination, start_cursor=cursor)

logging.info(time.time() - t0)
```

On the local development machine it takes nearly 2 seconds and there are less than 150 entities in the model

When live with around 800 entities it takes nearly 2 seconds to retrieve the first 250 entities and then around 4 seconds to retrieve the remainder. There are two separate requests to retrieve each set on the live machine.

I've set the time on the query only, therefore no other processing is taken into account in these timings.

Is this normal with fetch_page if so are there any reasonable alternatives to achieve the same?

Comment: Do not use the dev server as a basis for performance measurement.  It really has no relationship (due to implementation) when compared with a production runtime.  When looking at real runtime check that your first query isn't waiting for the server to start.  Then start looking at the logs and see how long each part takes.  You don't include any code called before or after the query, no anything you do with the query. 

Appengine isn't this slow. You also haven't include any indication how big your model is.

Comment: Tim, these are the times for the query not what i do before or after the query. See the code segment above. I tested both on the local dev server and the live server and the results are very consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.

What I had to do was take the main property of the model entities that I need to send to the client and save them to another new model.

The subsequent query does not require any equality tests on properties just a straight fetch_page and returns the larger set of data in 0.000469923019409ms compared to the 4 seconds it took the other query.

So the problem obviously lies in the amount of data that the model entities contain and have to retrieve.

The only downfall in this is that I had to do a large amount of redesign and have the same data in two places. The later of which cannot be avoided without major redesign.

Anyway, I'm a happy dev this evening.